# Time.time in unity

Tags: time

i see a video of how to move a cube like snake game move

HI
in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aT2zNLSFQEk&list=PLLH3mUGkfFCVNs51eK8ftCAlI3hZQ95tC&index=11 ) he declare float name **lastMove **with no value (zero by default) and use it in condition and **minus **it with **Time.time** then assign it to **lastMove **.
my question is what is **the effect of lastMove** in condition when it has no value?
if i clear it from "if statement" the game run fast but if remain in "if statement" time passed very slower

Answer (score 0):

What he does is check continuously if `time - lastMove` is bigger than a given predefined interval (`timeInBetweenMoves`). Time keeps increasing each frame while `lastMove` is fixed. So at some point this condition will be true. When it is, he updates `lastMove` with the value of time to "reset the loop" = to make the *minus* difference lower than the interval again.
The point of doing this is to move only at a fixed interval (0.25 secs) instead of every frame. Like this:

```
interval = 0.25 (timeBetweenMoves)

time (secs) | lastMove  | time - lastMove  
-----------------------------------------
0.00        | 0         | 0
0.05        | 0         | 0.05
0.10        | 0         | 0.10
0.15        | 0         | 0.15
0.20        | 0         | 0.20
0.25        | 0         | 0.25
0.30        | 0         | 0.30 ---> bigger than interval: MOVE and set lastMove to this (0.30)
0.35        | 0.30      | 0.5
0.40        | 0.30      | 0.10
0.45        | 0.30      | 0.15
0.50        | 0.30      | 0.20
0.55        | 0.30      | 0.25
0.60        | 0.30      | 0.30 ---> bigger than interval: MOVE and set lastMove to time (0.60)
0.65        | 0.60      | 0.5
0.70        | 0.60      | 0.10
...
```

This is kind of a throttling.

Comment: tnx . you help me understand :)

Comment: @PeaceSafe No prob. If you feel the answer is ok, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/266755) :)